# Why EMF induced in the coil acts to oppose any change in the magnetic flux?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, energy-conservation, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

This might be an absurd question for some of you guys.
According to Lenz's Law an induced current will create a magnetic field that induces another current in which it opposes the current causing it at the first place. My question is 'WHY' should it oppose?

I've seen answers on the Internet saying it's the matter of Conservation of Energy, I totally agree on that statement but it doesn't really 'click' my mind, as the statement is something I will always remember, not truly understand. So is there any other possible way to conceptualize/explain that?

Comment: I'm guessing an explanation that is just "because it is experimentally validated" isn't sufficient for you?

Comment: Do you want more explanation of the conservation of energy argument, or are you looking for a totally different argument for why the EMF is what it is?

Comment: You can think of a varying magnetic field inducing an electric field that in turn stablishes a current. This, together with Maxwell's equations may help you. Note that to stablish the current the circuit must be closed. If you want to recall energy conservation do not forget the Poynting vector.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens, yes, that was what I meant.

Comment: You may look at it as at a manifestation of inertia. For example, to give a body some velocity $V$ you must apply a force and make some work. In order to stop a moving body, you must apply the opposite force whose magnitude depends on the deceleration desired.

Comment: If not, then electromagnetic systems would be unstable.  Induced current would increase the field which would increase the current which would increase the field ... and so on.   (This is conservation of energy from a different perspective.)

Comment: in my mind there is also no intuitive reason to why the magnetic field induces current in the first place, so i cant really give intuition for the sign of this current. i think rigorously for maxwell equations intuition can be given considering lorentz invariance and noting they are the correct way to formulate a massless spin 1 theory. maybe lorentz invariance could be taken into account to get intuition of the minus sign

Comment: Does this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/682597/question-on-lenz-law answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question on Lenz law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/682597/question-on-lenz-law)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a **moving conductor cutting magnetic flux**, you can derive Lenz's law without obvious appeal to energy conservation. A simple set-up is a metal rod sliding on metal rails connected together by a resistor at one end. The rod, rails and resistor form a rectangle. A uniform magnetic field is applied at right angles to the plane of the rectangle.

Apply $\mathbf F_\parallel =q\mathbf v_\perp \times \mathbf B$ (or Fleming's left hand motor rule) to the charge carriers in the rod, whose velocity component, $\mathbf v_\perp$, at right angles to the rod is that of the rod itself as it made to slide along the rails by an external force. The force, $\mathbf F_\parallel$, on a carrier (if positively charged) acting along the rod is clearly the direction of the emf. The current driven by this emf gives rise to a force opposing the motion of the rod – we use $\mathbf F_\perp=q\mathbf v_\parallel \times \mathbf B$ (or Fleming's left hand motor rule) on the component, $\mathbf v_\parallel$, of carrier velocity *along* the rod. This agrees with with Lenz's law.

Algebraically we have
$$\mathbf F_\parallel =q\mathbf v_\perp \times \mathbf B$$
But the drift velocity, $\mathbf v_\parallel$ of carriers along the moving rod will be proportional to $\mathbf F_\parallel$, so we can write
$$\mathbf v_\parallel = a\mathbf F_\parallel\ \ \ \ \ \  \text{in which } a \text{ is a positive constant}$$
Therefore the force on the carriers due to their motion along the rod will be
$$\mathbf F_\perp\ =\ q\mathbf v_\parallel \times \mathbf B\ =\ qa\mathbf F_\parallel \times \mathbf B\ =\ q^2a(\mathbf v_\perp \times \mathbf B) \times \mathbf B\ =-\ q^2a\ \mathbf B \times (\mathbf v_\perp \times \mathbf B) =\ -q^2 a\ B^2 \mathbf v_\perp$$

• The last step used the BAC-CAB rule.

• The minus sign, embodying Lenz's law, arises whether the charge carriers have a positive or negative charge, as it is $q^2$ that appears.

This argument cannot, of course, be used for the other kind of e-m induction, where an **emf is induced in a stationary circuit by a changing magnetic field**. Here the emf arises from an induced *electric* field in the circuit. The electric field can be calculated using the Faraday-Maxwell equation $$\text{curl}\ \mathbf E = -\frac{d\mathbf B}{dt}.$$
The minus sign embodies Lenz's law, and the usual way to justify it is ... by appeal to energy conservation!

In certain special cases, such as thrusting a magnet into a coil, we can justify the minus sign by invoking the relativity principle...

The rod-on-rails argument above can be generalised to give the general equation for a moving circuit of any shape:
$$\mathscr E =-\frac {d\Phi}{dt}$$
This applies if we move the coil in the (non-uniform) field of a stationary magnet. According to the Relativity principle the same equation – with its minus sign – will apply if we move the magnet and keep the coil stationary. I'm unable, though, to extend the argument to include, for example, mutual induction.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are two parts to your question:

1. Why does it happen?
2. What is the best way to understand why this is conservation of energy.

The first though is very fundamental question. You are literally asking why is energy conserved. I would like an answer to that too.

The second is relatively easier. Whenever you see current flowing it is capable of doing some work or in another sense it is energy. e.g. it can cause a motor to run, lift a weight, power your pc and so on. Now if the magnetic field caused by the current would have aided the current which would have added more current and so on. You would have a perpetual machine!

Answer (score 0):

Let us just consider the classic experimental example of Lenz's law: a solenoid, and a bar magnet.

If we move the bar magnet, it induces an emf in the solenoid, current flows, and a magnetic field is induced.  This is due to Faraday's Law of electromagnetic induction.

Consider the scenario that Lenz's law doesn't hold, and the magnet experiences an attractive **force**, into the solenoid.  Which in turn leads to acceleration of the magnet, increasing $N\phi$ (magnetic flux linkage).  This leads to increased emf and current, which evidently violates the principle of conservation of energy.

Comment: So the explanantion is basically the conservation of energy? I mean I know it opposes because there's no way of creating/producing extra energy out of nothing, the thought I was facing was how and why it really opposes? But if this the only reason on this case, I'll just need to accept that.

Comment: @acmilan yes.  that is the reason why the "-" sign is added.