# Question on Lenz law

Tags: electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

According to Lenz's law , the direction of current induced in a coil is such that it opposes the very cause which produce it

Why is this so?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law#Definition) clearly states this is a consequence of Faraday's law of induction. Do you have a specific question about that?

Comment: What is the reason behind faradays law of induction , means , why the change magnetic  flux induce current in a conductor

Comment: What sort of "reason" are you looking for? For instance, the article on Faraday's law in turn contains a proof of Faraday's law from Maxwell's equations. The more specific you are about the *research you've done* and what exactly you want to know, the more likely it is you will receive an answer that actually tells you what you want!

Comment: Check page number 210 in this [textbook](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook.php?leph1=6)

Answer (score 3):

If we have a magnet moving into a solenoid, let's say with the North pole closest to the solenoid and the South pole further away.

The induced e.m.f in the solenoid turns it into an electromagnet with a North pole at one end and a South pole at the other.

[image]

If the direction of the induced current was such as to create a South at $A$, the magnet would be accelerated, gaining kinetic energy.  Energy is also generated as heat in the wires and this violates conservation of energy.

Therefore a North must be created at $A$ and a south at $B$

i.e. "the direction of the current induced in a coil is such that it opposes the cause that produce it".

Answer (score 3):

One way to look at Lenz's Law is as an example of conservation of energy.  If a current is induced electrical energy is generated.  We don't get this energy for free.  It comes as the cost of doing mechanical work against the electromagnetic force which is opposing the inducing action.

Answer (score 2):

Do you ask a technical question, solved by checking Faraday's law ?

Or a philosophical one, why is Faraday's law the way it is ?

If it were in the opposite way, a change of magnetic flux creating a current that increases it, any closed conducting loop that happens to undergo a change in the magnetic flux through it would induce a current that  increases it, indefinitely. That would be an infinite source of energy... The Universe could not survive with such laws....

Answer (score 2):

[image: Faraday induction and Lenz law]

Base image credits: [WP base image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law)

I will try to explain it as intuitive as possible using an analogy. The whole system behaves like a left handed screw (magnet $B_{1}$) and its corresponding right handed threads screw hole (current $I$ in a conductive loop, could be a spiral from a solenoid).

At **case (a)** nothing happens since we don't make any attempt to move the screw using our screwdriver in or out from the screw hole. Charges in the conductive loop wire are not pushed by the stationary magnet.

In **case (b)** the screw moves towards the hole by turning counterclockwise CCW (i.e. clockwise CW when the screw is observed from above its head, screw-in similar to right hand corkscrew rule) therefore the threads in the hole ($I$ current) move relative to the screw threads to the opposite direction thus clockwise CW when the hole is observed from bellow or counterclockwise CCW when observed from above. Similar to mechanical screw hole opposing the entrance of the screw, the current $I$ creates a magnetic field $B_{2}$ (see large orange vector at the inner side of the square black loop) that opposes the entrance of the magnet. As a reminder the arrow indicates the magnetic moment direction thus where the North magnetic pole is. Thus in case (b) here the N pole of the magnet is clashing with the N magnetic pole vector created inside the conductive black loop thus like poles and therefore we have repulsion. This is exactly the physical origin of the Lenz law expressed as the minus sign in the Faraday induction law:

$\varepsilon=-N \frac{\Delta \Phi}{\Delta t}$

\begin{array}{l}
\varepsilon=\text { induced voltage } \\
N=\text { number of loops } \\
\Delta \Phi=\text { change in magnetic flux } \\
\Delta t=\text { change in time }
\end{array}

In **case (c)** we now unscrew (i.e. magnet moves away from the loop) causing the opposite directional rotations of the field vectors from the ones described in *case (b)* above. Once more as in the mechanical analogy, the screw hole resists to the outward motion of the screw similar here the current $I$ creates a magnetic field inside the conductive black loop $B_{2}$ (see large orange vector) in the same direction of $B_{1}$ thus unlike poles are facing each other, N pole of magnet with S pole of conductive loop and therefore magnetic attraction is created that resists the outward motion of the magnet.

**Cases (d) & (e)** are similar to *cases (b) and (c)* but now the S pole of the magnet is  facing our conductive loop instead. Therefore, now our magnet behaves like a right handed screw (i.e. A Right handed screw, screws in by turning CCW on its head. A left handed screw, screws in by turning CW on its head) and our screw hole is now left handed relative to the screw. Again the magnetic field induced  in the conductive loop opposes the motion of the magnet.

---

The above described cases using the screw and screw hole analogy is actually close enough to reality since it is known that the magnetic field of a moving magnet induces a non-conservative rotational electrical field in a conductive loop wire that then creates current inside the loop which then creates a magnetic field around and along the loop (see orange field) that opposes the motion of the magnet moving towards or away from the loop's air cap, thus the Lenz law.

Here is a vector diagram of the electric field $E$, projected on a conductive loop generated by a moving magnet (i.e. colored circle at the center):

[image: irrotational elctric field]

image credits: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmlnGei1xo8

The total electric field $E$ shown above is [irrotational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field) in three dimensions and simply connected (i.e. has a vanishing curl, like a vortex) therefore is a conservative electric field in total. However, these vectors of the field which coincide spatially with the wire of the loop are forming a rotational non-conservative electric field induced inside the wire of the loop.

Notice also on the first top figure presented, that only the coherent direction vectors of the $B_{2}$ field which are inside the loop's air cap do matter in the Lenz effect. In a multiple loops coaxial configuration thus an electrical solenoid, these vectors from one spiral of the solenoid to other are coupled along the solenoid forming an almost homogeneous irrotational magnetic field $B_{2}$ inside the solenoid that opposes the motion of the magnet according to Lenz law.

[image: solenoid]

Comment: The magnetic lines generated by a coil must be in circular shape , then why in the given diagram 'B2' is in upward/downward  direction

Comment: @VaibhavTiwari Good question. As I've written in my answer, last paragraph, "Notice here that only the coherent direction vectors of the B2 field which are inside the loop's air cap do matter in this phenomenon."  the magnetic vectors of $B_{2}$ field are going circular and concentric around the wire but only these vectors that inside the loop are contributing to the Lenz effect (see left half  of orange circle) and especially these $B_{2}$ vectors that coincide with the movement axis of the magnet.

Comment: @VaibhavTiwari Also notice the B2 magnetic field (orange circles) concentrically arround and along the wire loop, extends inside the loop's air cap (not shown in the figures).

Comment: @VaibhavTiwari I've updated my answer with new figure showing the rotational electric field induced inside the wire of a loop by the motion of a magnet.

Comment: why only the coherent direction vectors of B2 which are inside the loops air cap do matter

Comment: @VaibhavTiwari Because these vectors are the ones who mostly contribute to the Lenz effect and are the strongest. The Lenz effect is taking place always in the space inside the loop where the field in concentrated and the strongest and not outside where the field is spread out and very weak.

Comment: Ok , coherent direction  vectors inside loop matters . But what about their direction , why it is shown in upward or downward direction

Comment: @VaibhavTiwari Right hand corkscrew rule. Your thumb points in the direction of the current $I$ vector and the rest of the fingers bend around the wire. The B2 vectors are tangential at any point of this circle. There are not just two B2 vectors but many around the orange circle tangential to the perimeter of the circle. https://web.pa.msu.edu/courses/1997spring/PHY232/lectures/ampereslaw/wire.html#:~:text=Magnetic%20field%20of%20a%20wire&text=Magnetic%20fields%20arise%20from%20charges,that%20generates%20a%20magnetic%20field.

Comment: Pls answer one last time , what are these b2 vectors , I was only taught that there is a magnetic field vector which are in circular shape around the wire , what are these tangential B2 vectors

Comment: @VaibhavTiwari There  is no such thing as an circular shaped vector! Vectors are always straight arrows. The B2 vectors are tangential to any point of the circle. (circle represents the magnetic flux trajectory not the vectors)